# Finding minimal polynomial of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let$$  T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $$

be linear transformation of orthogonal projection, on:
$$ 2x - y + z = 0 $$

How can I find the **minimal polynomial of T**?

Tried finding the characteristic polynomial and maybe extract from him the minimal polynomial, but with not success of finding the characteristic polynomial.

Thank in advance, much appreciated

Comment: As a hint: a projector $T$ has the property $T^2 = T$.

Comment: @trancelocation Where can I use this information?

Comment: So, $x^2-x$ is a polynomial that "annihilates" $T$. Hope, this is hint enough.